# org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: [warning] org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: timeout

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jetty, cxf

I am using apache karaf container along with jetty, spring and cxf.
And noticed lot of warning while authenticating using spring security.

Tried to find the information on web, but could not find much.
Anybody experienced similar issue. Why such warnings? Will it impact?

**Code Snippet**

`public void prepareSecurityContext(ServletRequest request,
            ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, MeetingRef user,
            String username, String token) throws IOException, ServletException    {`

```
    // Build an Authentication object with the user's info
    AbstractAuthenticationToken auth = new UserTokenAuthentication(
            username, token, getAuthorities(user));

    auth.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource()
            .buildDetails((HttpServletRequest) request));
    // Set the authentication into the SecurityContext
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);

    // Continue through the filter chain
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

**Below is the snippet of exception stacktrace:**

`2015-07-23T09:37:42.0 localhost.localdomain     org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: [warning]  org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: timeout
2015-07-23T09:37:42.0 localhost.localdomain     at [warning]  org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBody(JAXRSUtils.java:1243)
2015-07-23T09:37:42.0 localhost.localdomain     at [warning]  org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameter(JAXRSUtils.java:782)
2015-07-23T09:37:42.0 localhost.localdomain     at [warning]  org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameters(JAXRSUtils.java:741)`

......................................................

2015-07-23T09:37:42.0 localhost.localdomain     Caused [warning]  by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: timeout
2015-07-23T09:37:42.0 localhost.localdomain     at [warning]  org.apache.cxf.attachment.LazyAttachmentCollection.loadAll(LazyAttachmentCollection.java:58)
2015-07-23T09:37:42.0 localhost.localdomain     at [warning]
.......................................................
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
2015-07-23T09:37:42.0 localhost.localdomain     at [warning]  com.mypackage.UserAuthenticationProcessingFilter.prepareSecurityContext(UserAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:132)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try manually setting the authentication this way please :

```
// Below gets the object from the database for the user which you want to authenticate. 
    Person person1 = this.personService.findPersonByUsername(username);
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
// Add the role of the user
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(person1, null, authorities);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

Try this out and please post the log a bit more properly with proper formatting, because of which it's only possible to see warnings now, and flow is not understandable. Lemme know if this helps.

Comment: Thank for the reply. I think issue is with the link mentioned at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cometd-users/aJFjUizBYKk . I will continue monitoring the issue and see how frequently it is occuring.

Comment: no, i have not tried, thank you for the sussgestion. it was different issue.